# python requests adding session variable and its value

Tags: python, session, python-requests

I am writing a python script to submit a post request with data. I got the below programme which works fine for login. and i get value "cloud" for a.text. but i am not able to submit next post request to the server because the in php application i have isset($_SESSION['user_name']. if user_name is not set then it will redirect to homepage. the below code redirects to home page. I want to set the a.text to $_SESSION[user_name]. how to do it

```
import requests
loginurl = 'http:localhost/login.php'
loginparams = {'username': 'admin', 'password' : '1234'}
targeturl = 'http:localhost/add.php'
params={'firstname':'cloud', 'lastname':'kicker'}

def main():
    login = requests.Session()
    a = login.post(loginurl, loginparams)
    print a.text # i get username for this line
    login.post(targeturl, params, cookies={'user_name': a.text})
    return 0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

i updated the below line and it worked for me

```
login.post(targeturl, params, cookies={'user_name': a.text})

login.post(targeturl, targetdata, cookies=dict(login.cookies))
```